# Can't build Postgres with SSL although libssl-dev is installed

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, cross-compiling, gnu-make, configure

I'm currently trying to build a version of Postgres myself but I have some issues with the SSL support.

I configure the project with (cross compiling for Windows)

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-openssl --prefix=/home/fuchs/postgres-bin-9.6.12
```

But I get an error

```
checking for library containing gethostbyname_r... no
checking for library containing shmget... no
checking for inflate in -lz... yes
checking for library containing CRYPTO_new_ex_data... no
configure: error: library 'eay32' or 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL
```

I searched the internet for a solution and found that installing libssl-dev should fix the issue (and it seems like it helped some people). I checked and libssl-dev was already installed.
Since the error does not actually mention SSL I searched for libraries like `eay32` and `crypto` and could find several packages called `libcrypto++-dev` and similar which were already installed but from what I understand libcrypto should be part of the ssl library.

I checked `configure.in` for the source of the error and found

```
if test "$with_openssl" = yes ; then
  dnl Order matters!
  if test "$PORTNAME" != "win32"; then
     AC_CHECK_LIB(crypto, CRYPTO_new_ex_data, [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([library 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL])])
     AC_CHECK_LIB(ssl,    SSL_new, [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([library 'ssl' is required for OpenSSL])])
  else
     AC_SEARCH_LIBS(CRYPTO_new_ex_data, [eay32 crypto], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([library 'eay32' or 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL])])
     AC_SEARCH_LIBS(SSL_new, [ssleay32 ssl], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([library 'ssleay32' or 'ssl' is required for OpenSSL])])
  fi
```

Unfortunately I have pretty much no experience with make, autoconf and these build tools but from what I understand it's simply trying to find the libraries ssl and crypto but cant.

So I tried explicitly adding the include and lib directories

```
/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-openssl --with-includes=/usr/include/openssl/ --with-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ --prefix=/home/fuchs/postgres-bin-9.6.12
```

however it didn't change anything and now I'm out of ideas. I'm on Kubuntu 18.04, pretty much a fresh install and try to build Postgres 9.6.12.

Comment: Having similar issues. In my case, I am trying to cross compile the library. Despite setting the --with-includes and --with-libraries flags to point to the correct openssl, still can't get the script to find openssl!